# Obtaining log-likelihood value of a Markov chain when probability transition matrix contains exact-zero entries

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, markov-process

I have a $n$ sequences $\boldsymbol{X}_1, \dots, \boldsymbol{X}_n$ of varying lengths arising from a Markov chain with a large state space $\mathcal{S} = \{ 1, 2, \dots, s \}$. Suppose the initial state probabilities are $\boldsymbol{\pi} = (\pi_1, \dots, \pi_s)^\top$ and the transition probability matrix is denoted by
$$\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{bmatrix} P_{11} & P_{12} & \cdots & P_{1s} \\ P_{21} & P_{22} & \cdots & P_{2s} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ P_{s1} & P_{s2} & \cdots & P_{ss} \end{bmatrix}.$$
Herein, I am interested in obtaining the maximum likelihood estimates for $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ and $\boldsymbol{P}$. The log-likelihood function for $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ and $\boldsymbol{P}$ can be written as
$$l (\boldsymbol{\pi}, \boldsymbol{P}; \boldsymbol{x}_1, \dots, \boldsymbol{x}_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \left[ \sum_{j = 1}^s I (x_{i1} = j) \log \pi_j + \sum_{h = 1}^s \sum_{k = 1}^s c_{ihk} \log P_{hk} \right],$$
where $x_{i1}$ is the first state of sequence $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ and $c_{ihk}$ is the number of transitions from state $h$ to state $k$ within sequence $\boldsymbol{x}_i$. So, basically, for each sequence, we will have a transition frequency matrix $\boldsymbol{C}_i$. I was able to obtain the MLEs for $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ and $\boldsymbol{P}$ but in my case, because I have a large state space with some transitions occurring very rarely, I want to further impose a constraint that some entries in $\boldsymbol{P}$ to be exactly 0. I was then able to tweak the traditional MLE formulas to fulfill the constraint, but I ran into the problem of obtaining the log-likelihood value since $\log(0)$ is undefined. Computation-wise, I can replace those exact zeros with some small number like $0.0001$, but I think this approach is quite arbitrary and context-dependent (works in some cases but not all).

Does anyone have any ideas on this matter? Please help me if you can. Thank you so much.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem; if the probability of an event is equal to zero, the event shouldn't have occurred, so shouldn't have contributed to the log-likelihood at all.

Comment: Thank you. But I think I need to add a little bit more. There are some transitions that did occur but very rarely so the probability estimates came out very low so I want to try constraining them to be exactly 0. I want to obtain the log-likelihood value because I want to compare one setup where some entries are 0 to another setup where some other entries are 0. Please let me know if I can do anything about it. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, but it makes no sense to assign a probability of zero to a transition that actually occurred.  Naturally, you will have problems with the likelihood function if you do so.  The MLE for the transition probability from state $i$ to $j$ will be the observed proportion of transitions to $j$ from $i$; why not just use that?  Are you attempting something akin to regularization of the estimates?

Comment: Thank you. I understand the concern and I myself also doubt my approach. Since I have many states and some transitions are just like 9 or 10 out of millions of total transitions, it comes to the problem of having many parameters to estimate, so restricting some to be 0 can reduce the number a bit. You are right that I am heading to some regularization of the estimates: where to place zeros on the probability transition matrix makes the most sense. There will be some schemes of penalization, but I think in the first step, I should make sure I can obtain the log-likelihood value sensibly.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ ? Is it $\pi$ ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, you are right. It should be $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ I fixed the post. Thank you.